# Message while accessing lotus notes application at Lotus Designer

Tags: xpages

I have Manager rights at the ACL of an application .When I open this application from designer it gives me below error

"you cannot view the design of this database because it is hidden "

I dont know what went wrong with this application . Can any one help

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" but the design has been hidden - see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_HIDING_THE_DESIGN_OF_A_DATABASE.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to the template (usually an .ntf- file) of the database.

The design of the database was hidden when replacing the design using a template. 
There is NO WAY to access the design of the database anymore.

There was a hack some years ago where you could open SOME of the design- elements by editing some bits in the nsf with a HEX- editor, but this does not help you at all as it does not make the relevant code visible.

Wihtout access to the template that was used to create the database there is no chance for you to do anything with the design of that database anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have not hide the design, until the afternoon I was working quite fine with this application. And no changes in template or design has been done. How can a design set itself as hide automatically